# Backbone events that are used across multiple views

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I plan on using multiple popups on my website. Every popup will be rendered by a different view. How can I share certain events, like clicking outside of the popup to close it, across these multiple views that each use a popup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using backbone's built-in extend could be a good fit for this. You could have a base view like so:

```
MyApp.PopupView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // ... your shared code here ...
})
```

And all your other popups could extend the base popup:

```
MyApp.UserPopupView = MyApp.PopupView.extend({
  // ... user popup specific view code here ...
})
```

It's worth noting that any properties including `events` that you specify in a child view will override the properties in the parent. To avoid this, you'll need to either merge the parent's values (in the case of events) or set them programmatically using `delegateEvents` ([documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)).

Comment: Is there a benefit to using `MyApp.PopupView` over `PopupView`? Also, how would I call `PopupView`'s render function inside my `UserPopupView` render function?

Comment: The benefit to namespacing is that you avoid naming collisions with other libraries, especially when more ambiguous names are used. In order to call the "superclass" function you would need to use apply like: `MyApp.PopupView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments)` from `MyApp.UserPopupView.render()`